# Is it possible to pad a C/C++ structure to a fixed size using a compile time calculation?

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to compute at compile time the size of a padding array required in a structure such that the structure ends up being a per-determined size. That is I would like to do something like this (which I know won't work)

```
#define APPDESCTARGETSIZE       256         // Target size for the App Desc Structure

// Structure member size of
#define msizeof(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member)

// Size of padding arrary
#define padsize     (APPDESCTARGETSIZE - (offsetof(custom_app_desc_t, pad) + msizeof(custom_app_desc_t, tail)))

/**  * @brief Description about application.  */ 
typedef struct {
    uint8_t   header[16];
    char      progname[16];
    char      boardname[16];
    uint8_t   chipsize;
    uint8_t   version_maj;
    uint8_t   version_min;
    uint8_t   version_iss;
    uint8_t   pad[padsize];
    uint8_t   tail[16]; 
 } custom_app_desc_t;
```

I can solve with a manual calculation such as below but it would nice for the compiler to do math for me:

```
#define padsize     (APPDESCTARGETSIZE - 68)
```

NOTE, it is important in this case that pad occurs before the 'tail' member.

Comment: You should decide if you want to do this in C (solution based on macros) or C++ (solution based on templates and constexpr)

Comment: Do you want to use/access the `pad` field? Please [edit] your question to answer. Maybe you could use a union.

Comment: Lets assume C and macros etc

Comment: You get error such as this: lib\RR_OTA_Update\src/custAppDesc.h:46:73: error: 'struct custom_app_desc_t' has no member named 'pad'
 const size_t padsize = (APPDESCTARGETSIZE - offsetof(custom_app_desc_t, pad) + msizeof(custom_app_desc_t, tail));

Comment: The pad member is not accessed as it is only intended to reserve space for future structure members.

Comment: @KamilCuk : Can you show where to use the offsetof() ? I get the above compiler error in my attempt. Because structure is not declared prior to the define. Hence the catch 22 !!

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve this is with a `union`:

```
struct {
    union {
        struct {
            // this is your structure, without the last element
        };
        char _reserved[APPDESCTARGETSIZE - 16]; // exclude the last tail element
    };
    char tail[16]; // the tail is outside of the padding
};
```

Comment: Can you explain why last element is not included in the union?

Comment: You can leave the name off of the inner struct so that its members can be accessed directly.

Comment: A semi-colon is missing after the union's closing brace.

Comment: `_data` is not needed

Comment: @TanveerBadar: So that it is after the padding, as requested in the question.

Comment: I had missed that bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

the easiest IMO way is to wrap into another struct.

```
#define APPDESCTARGETSIZE       256  
#define TAILSIZE    16
#define TAILTYPE    uint8_t

typedef struct {
    struct internal{
        uint8_t   header[16];
        char      progname[16];
        char      boardname[16];
        uint8_t   chipsize;
        uint8_t   version_maj;
        uint8_t   version_min;
        uint8_t   version_iss;
    }fields;
    uint8_t   pad[APPDESCTARGETSIZE - sizeof(struct internal) - sizeof(TAILTYPE) * TAILSIZE];
    TAILTYPE   tail[TAILSIZE]; 
 } custom_app_desc_t;
```

or as _Blindy (but using anonymous structure)

```
#define APPDESCTARGETSIZE       256  
#define TAILSIZE    16
#define TAILTYPE    uint8_t

typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t   header[16];
            char      progname[16];
            char      boardname[16];
            uint8_t   chipsize;
            uint8_t   version_maj;
            uint8_t   version_min;
            uint8_t   version_iss;
        };
        struct {
            uint8_t _dummy[APPDESCTARGETSIZE - sizeof(TAILTYPE) * TAILSIZE];
        };
    };
    TAILTYPE   tail[TAILSIZE]; 
 } custom_app_desc_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using unnamed union and structure members, you can control the layout for your purpose:

```
#define APPDESCTARGETSIZE  256    // Target size for the App Desc Structure

/**  * @brief Description about application.  */ 
typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t   header[16];
            char      progname[16];
            char      boardname[16];
            uint8_t   chipsize;
            uint8_t   version_maj;
            uint8_t   version_min;
            uint8_t   version_iss;
        };
        uint8_t   pad0[APPDESCTARGETSIZE - 16];
    };
    uint8_t   tail[16]; 
} custom_app_desc_t;
```

You can access the members simply as if they were members of `custom_app_desc_t`:

```
    custom_app_desc_t obj;
    get_app_desc(&obj);
    printf("progname: %s\n", obj.progname);
```

This handy syntax trick is called *anonymous union* and *anonymous structure*.

The size of the anonymous union is the largest of the size of each of its members, ie: the structure with your named members and the byte array `pad0`.
Since the named members amount to less than `APPDESCTARGETSIZE-16` bytes, the union size is exactly `APPDESCTARGETSIZE-16` which is the goal of the exercise.

If you need to access the padding bytes, you could add an extra member at the end of the inner structure `uint8_t pad[1];`

If the `tail` part is not a simple byte array, you need to define a structure type for it and subtract its size instead of 16.

Comment: @0___________: oops, I misread the spec. Fixed now.

Comment: I would not use hardcoded 16 if I want some kind generic solution.