# How to automatically pad bytes in a structure to a specific alignment?

Tags: c, memory-alignment

For example, I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct st
{
    char x1;
    char x2;
    ...
    char y;
}*st_p;
```

This definition of structure `st` may vary over time (it is not guaranteed what will be defined inside `...` as development goes on).

Is there a way to guarantee that `char y` is always aligned on – for example – a 256-byte boundary?

I guess the solution is something like adding an array like the following:

```
typedef struct st
{
    char x1;
    char x2;
    ...
    char padding[keyword];
    char y;
}*st_p;
```

Is there such a `keyword` which calculates the total size of all previous members in this structure and which thereby helps resolve the number of bytes to pad?

Comment: The C standard has `_Alignas`; you can use `char _Alignas(256) y;`. It does not require C implementations to support extended alignments, so that will not work in all C implementations. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66066859/298225) for alternative solutions.

Comment: Note that any attempt to add the necessary padding manually will only ensure that the subsequent member is at a 256-byte multiple offset from the start of the structure; if an instance of that structure is not, itself, 256-byte aligned, then nor will the relevant member(s) be.

Answer (score 3):

Since C11, the C language [includes the `_Alignas` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas),<sup>1</sup> with which you can specify a desired (minimum) alignment requirement for any object, including a member of a structure.

So, in your case, you can skip the 'manual' padding and just add that attribute to the `char y;` declaration:

```c
typedef struct st {
    char x1;
    char x2;
    //...
    _Alignas(256) char y;
}*st_p;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> However, note that the C Standard does not *require* that an implementation supports so-called "extended alignment" – that is, an alignment requirement that is greater than that of a `max_align_t` type (typically 8 or 16 bytes). What it *does* require, though, is that the specified alignment be a positive power of 2 (which is true, in your case).

---

As an addendum/alternative, I shall also address your direct question:

> *Is there such a keyword which calculates the total size of all previous members in this structure and which thereby helps resolve the
> number of bytes to pad?*

The 'keyword' (actually, an *operator*) that could be used here is `sizeof` – so long as you put "all previous members" inside an anonymous `struct`. Here's an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct st {
    struct inner {
        char x1;
        char x2;
        char x3[714];
        //...
    };
    char padding[256 - sizeof(struct inner) % 256];
    char y;
}*st_p;

int main()
{
    struct st test;
    test.x1 = 'A'; // You can access the anonymous structure members as though
    test.x2 = 'B'; // they were 'direct' members of the enclosing structure.
    printf("%c %c %zu\n", test.x1, test.x2, offsetof(struct st, y));// Offset is 768
    return 0;
}
```

But note that, in this code, although the *offset* of `y` will be a multiple of 256 bytes, that *doesn't guarantee* that `y` will be 256-byte aligned. That will only be true in an instance of the `st` structure that *is itself* aligned on a 256-byte boundary … and to ensure that, you will need an alignment attribute on the structure itself.

Comment: The C standard does not require `_Alignas(256)` to be supported. It only requires support for “fundamental alignments,” which are those needed for the arithmetic, enumerated, and pointer types.

Comment: @Eric Noted - see edit.

Comment: 2nd code is OK except when `sizeof(struct inner) == 256`.

Comment: @chux Yeah - getting rid of the padding when it's not needed requires considerably more trickery.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the compiler attributes to tell it to align a particular structure field to a specific bound. For example, if you are using GCC, you can use:

```
__attribute__((aligned(n)))
```

Thus, your example would become:

```
typedef struct st
{
    char x1;
    char x2;
    ...
    char __attribute__((aligned(256))) y;
}*st_p;
```

If you have to do this at several places, you can even imagine defining a special type for this, something like:

```
typedef char __attribute__((aligned(256))) aligned_char;

typedef struct st
{
    char x1;
    char x2;
    ...
    aligned_char y;
}*st_p;
```

This is not limited to structures field, you can also apply this to local or global variables.

However, keep in mind this may not work with all compilers as the attributes are binded to the compiler and not the C language.

If you are using MSCV, you may be able to replicate the behavior with

```
__declspec(align(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use a `union`, but there is no `.padding[]` member.  Could also use a check that the offset is correct in case the first `struct` is larger than desired offset.

```
#define OFFSET 256  /* Does not need to be a power-of-2 */

typedef struct st {
  union  {
    struct {
      char x1;
      char x2;
    };
    struct {
      char dummy[OFFSET];
    };
  };
  char y;
} st;

void bar(void) {
  st o1;
  o1.x1 = '1';
  o1.x2 = '2';
  o1.y = 'y';
  printf("%p\n", (void *) &o1);
  printf("%p\n", (void *) &o1.y);
}

_Static_assert(offsetof(struct st, y) == OFFSET, "TBD code");
```

Sample output

```
0xffffcac0
0xffffcbc0
```

This does not insure the *alignment* is 256, but that the offset of member `y` is 256 - which I think is OP's true goal.  [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177236/how-to-automatically-pad-bytes-in-a-structure-to-a-specific-alignment/73177715#comment129239679_73177236)